# How to check what numbers in a range have the same digit in the ones and tens place? (Python)

Tags: python, loops, if-statement, range

I'm new to coding. So far I've learned if statements and loops. I have a homework assignment to check which numbers between a range of 10 and 100 have the same numbers in the tens and ones place (11, 22, etc). I'm thinking if I can test which numbers are divisible by 11 I can generate the list I want, however I'm struggling on getting the program to test numbers in a range and give the output. I'm not even sure if I'm on the right track. Looking up things online hasn't helped either.

I'm not looking for anyone to do my homework for me, I just need a pointer in the right direction for what to do.

```
#This is something I tried based on something I found online, and it just output "Error" over and over
for i in range (10,100):
    count = 0
    if i%11==0:
        count=count+1
    else:
        print("Error.")
```

Comment: No need for a `continue`, just drop the else entirely. This function should only do something when it's divisible by 11, otherwise it will automatically go to the next iteration.

Comment: You're definitely going to be looking at some numbers that are not divisible by 11, so it's a normal case, not an error. I suspect they wanted you to use docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#divmod to extract the actual digits, but your approach seems better, given the specific restrictions. But you cannot extend your solution to other ranges, so it doesn't really solve anything in code. Wouldn't it be better to just "return 9" for the known answer on one known range?

Comment: Don't test when you can generate: `range(11, 100, 11)`.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, welcome to programming!

Considering you just started, just gotta say that you will always stumble and might even feel stuck at some points, but just know that literally everyone goes through said phases, probably even more so in programming related fields than other ones. With that being said, if you push through it you will eventually have an amazing skill that allows you to produce rather than consume!

It seems you have solved your issue, but to give you another solution you could have used. So, you have a million different ways that you could do this, but an interesting way that you could do this from a purely mathematical point (i.e. not using a special "integrated" method in python) is to use the modulo operator (%) and dividing the value by 10

By getting the answer of your "i" and modulo 10, you can find the rightmost digit of your number => `myNuber = i % 10` (e.g. 56 % 10 = 6)

After that, divide your number by ten to remove that rightmost digit => `56 / 10` which (in this example) will give you 5 (Never round up!)

Basically, now you have two different values, the 5 and the 6 (1 and 1 or 2 and 2 for 11 and 22). Well, I think you got the rest from here ;)

Good luck on your programming journey!